# How to only run one group or test

Tags: flutter

I want to run an individual group or test in the flutter throw command line for my better automation testing for a particular feature.

Comment: automation testing normally is done by specialized platforms like jenkins, bamboo & teamcity.
Dev ops engineers job is to configure those platforms to run the CI/CD including the unit tests.

Answer (score 6):

```
flutter test test/path/to/file --name yourGroupName
```

For example:

```
flutter test test/myApp/products_repository.dart --name getAllProducts
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can restrict dart/flutter tests to run with almost infinite granularity:

To run only a single flutter test:

`flutter test --name nameOfTest`

Or a group of tests:

`flutter test --name nameOfGroup`

Note that the string value of `-n`/`--name` is interpreted as a regular expression, so you can be as selective or general as you need for particular tests. If you want it interpreted as a plain text string, use `-N` instead.

And as @Eibo notes, you can restrict name/group matches to a specific file, if you happen to repeat the test name elsewhere in your project:

`flutter test test/my_controller_tests.dart --name nameOfTest`

You can also TAG tests within your testing code, then run tests that match that tag:

`flutter test --tags chrome`

eg, taken from the dart test page:

```
void main() {
  test('launches two browsers at once', () {
    // ...
  }, tags: ['chrome', 'firefox']);
}
```

The command line help has a great list of CLI args:

`flutter test --help`

The Dart test package page applies to flutter testing:
https://pub.dev/packages/test